# Best way to import and handle non-rectangular (ragged) data

Tags: apl, dyalog

I am studying APL and I am facing this problem: in real life cases, it is common to deal with non-rectangular datasets (imagine importing data from a SQL database where the "count(*) ... group by ..." gives different counts for different groups). I have setup an example where I import a time series of currencies exchange rates (both with `⎕CSV` and `⎕JSON`) and I end up with a table with lot of rows and three columns, the ISO code, the reference date and the rate. I find this table is useless in many cases, for instance if one wants to calculate daily return rates. I have manage to transform this table into a two entries table with Iso Codes in rows and dates in columns. I'd like to know if there are better ways to achieve this (or better) result.

```
(d h)←⎕csv 'dayliesjan.csv' '' (0 1 0 4 0 1)  1 ⍝ remove header row from data
```

This creates table d with rows that look like this:

```
├───┼──────────┼──────────┤
│FJD│2.451     │2024-01-10│
├───┼──────────┼──────────┤
│FJD│2.4514    │2024-01-29│
├───┼──────────┼──────────┤
│FJD│2.4523    │2024-01-12│
├───┼──────────┼──────────┤
```

Then

```
dates←∪d[;3]            ⍝ create a vector of unique dates
isos←∪d[;1]             ⍝ create a vector of unique isos
hdates←(⊂'---'),dates   ⍝ prepare a header for the two entries table
```

PRint the two entries table

```
hdates⍪isos,(≢isos) (≢dates) ⍴ d[{⊃⍵}⌸d[;1 3];2]
```

```
┌───┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬
│---│2024-01-02│2024-01-03│2024-01-04│2024-01-05│2024-01-08│2024-01-09│2024-01-10│
├───┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼
│AFN│76.7668   │76.7351   │77.1061   │76.8808   │77.2931   │77.1918   │77.3973   │
├───┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼
│ALL│103.17    │103.2     │103.88    │104.3     │104.47    │104.29    │104.28    │
├───┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼
│DZD│147.147   │146.9074  │147.3182  │146.7768  │147.0278  │146.9367  │147.0292  │
├───┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼
│AOA│917.42    │914.384   │917.186   │914.427   │916.706   │916.444   │917.425   │
├───┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼
│XCD│2.9581    │2.9481    │2.9573    │2.9487    │2.9554    │2.9538    │2.9554    │
├───┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼
│ARS│886.1662  │885.2383  │888.5621  │886.6029  │889.3809  │890.4455  │891.496   │
├───┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼
│AMD│443.13    │441.54    │443.1     │441.75    │442.66    │442.4     │443.14    │
├───┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼
│AWG│1.9611    │1.9545    │1.9606    │1.9549    │1.9593    │1.9583    │1.9593    │
├───┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼
```

On such a table I could easily (so I think) calculate daily return rates.

Does this make sense? Is there a better way?

Comment: Going forward, probably notice that you get a preview of what your post will look like below the editing pane. If your screen is wide enough, you also get a help button at the right of the editor's menu strip, with a link to the full [editing help.](/editing-help)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Really, all you want is the exchange rate for all combinations of isos and dates. This calls for an outer product:

```
      isos∘.{⍺ ⍵}dates
┌────────────────┬────────────────┬────────────────┬────────────────┬─────────────
│┌───┬──────────┐│┌───┬──────────┐│┌───┬──────────┐│┌───┬──────────┐│┌───┬────────
││AFN│2024-01-02│││AFN│2024-01-03│││AFN│2024-01-04│││AFN│2024-01-05│││AFN│2024-01-
│└───┴──────────┘│└───┴──────────┘│└───┴──────────┘│└───┴──────────┘│└───┴────────
├────────────────┼────────────────┼────────────────┼────────────────┼─────────────
│┌───┬──────────┐│┌───┬──────────┐│┌───┬──────────┐│┌───┬──────────┐│┌───┬────────
││ALL│2024-01-02│││ALL│2024-01-03│││ALL│2024-01-04│││ALL│2024-01-05│││ALL│2024-01-
│└───┴──────────┘│└───┴──────────┘│└───┴──────────┘│└───┴──────────┘│└───┴────────
├────────────────┼────────────────┼────────────────┼────────────────┼─────────────
│┌───┬──────────┐│┌───┬──────────┐│┌───┬──────────┐│┌───┬──────────┐│┌───┬────────
││DZD│2024-01-02│││DZD│2024-01-03│││DZD│2024-01-04│││DZD│2024-01-05│││DZD│2024-01-
│└───┴──────────┘│└───┴──────────┘│└───┴──────────┘│└───┴──────────┘│└───┴────────
├────────────────┼────────────────┼────────────────┼────────────────┼─────────────
```

For each combination, we want the row number in `d`:

```
      isos∘.{d[;1 3]⍳⍺ ⍵}dates
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7
 8  9 10 11 12 13 14
15 16 17 18 19 20 21
22 23 24 25 26 27 28
29 30 31 32 33 34 35
36 37 38 39 40 41 42
43 44 45 46 47 48 49
50 51 52 53 54 55 56
```

Now it is trivial to get the rate:

```
      isos∘.{d[d[;1 3]⍳⍺ ⍵;2]}dates
 76.7668  76.7351  77.1061  76.8808  77.2931  77.1918  77.3973
103.17   103.2    103.88   104.3    104.47   104.29   104.28  
147.147  146.9074 147.3182 146.7768 147.0278 146.9367 147.0292
917.42   914.384  917.186  914.427  916.706  916.444  917.425 
  2.9581   2.9481   2.9573   2.9487   2.9554   2.9538   2.9554
886.1662 885.2383 888.5621 886.6029 889.3809 890.4455 891.496 
443.13   441.54   443.1    441.75   442.66   442.4    443.14  
  1.9611   1.9545   1.9606   1.9549   1.9593   1.9583   1.9593
```

From here, you can add the headers if you want, but that'll just make usage of the table harder.

---

You can maybe make the code easier to follow through naming:

```
      isos_dates←d[;1 3]
      rates←d[;2]
      isos∘.{rates[isos_dates⍳⍺ ⍵]}dates
 76.7668  76.7351  77.1061  76.8808  77.2931  77.1918  77.3973
```

Or even creating a custom lookup function:

```
      RateOn←{rates[isos_dates⍳⍺ ⍵]}
      isos ∘.RateOn dates
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just one more thing: is it ok the way I used the ⌸ key operator to associate rates to codes and dates, or did it work only for a lucky arrangement of the incoming data?

Comment: @Alberto It only works because your data was ordered first by iso then by date. `{⊃⍵}⌸` is just an obscure `⍳≢` as each iso–date combo is unique. `{⊃⍵}⌸'lucky data'` gives `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`.

Comment: After some further experimenting I have found that using the outer product is right, but there is a catch: it only works if the incoming data is "rectangular".

Comment: @Alberto Yes, but it is easy to handle missing data: `RateOn←{(rates,'-')[isos_dates⍳⍺ ⍵]}` will put a dash where no rate is available.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a viable way to handle ragged data, using the "outer product" and the "index of" operators

```
(rates_as_imported csv_header)←⎕csv 'dailyrates.csv' '' (0 1 0 4 0 1) 1

⍝ Next I sort everything by iso code and date (may be useless, but I like it)

sort_by_iso_dates← ⍋rates_as_imported[;1 3]

sorted_rates←rates_as_imported[sort_by_iso_dates;]

⍝ The next three rows create labels for printing

isos← ∪rates_as_imported[sort_by_iso_dates;1]
dates←∪rates_as_imported[sort_by_iso_dates;3]
hdates←(⊂'---'),dates
isos_dates←rates_as_imported[sort_by_iso_dates;1 3]

DefaultValue←('-',¯1.0,'-')

⍝ generate the final table using the "index of" ⍳ dyadic: the (iso, date) pairs that have no associated value are replaced

rates_final←(sorted_rates⍪DefaultValue)[isos_dates ⍳ ↑isos∘.{⍺ ⍵}dates;2]
```